Negative bete value for Polygenic Risk Score (PRS) caiculation
I am learning to calculate the Polygenic Risk Score (PRS) for a disease.
However, I am confused about the $\beta$ used in the formula:
$$
\text{PRS} = \sum_{i=1}^N \beta_i\times G_i
$$
$\beta_i$ is the beta value for $SNP_i$ from the GWAS.
$G_i$ is the number of effect alleles (0, 1, or 2) that the individual has for $SNP_i$.
$N$ is the total number of SNPs used in the PRS.
I found two methods to do with it.

Use the original $\beta$, which can be either positive or negative, then the PRS can also be positive or negative.
Pubmed ID 30104762, 35324888, 34995502.

Convert the negative $\beta$ into positive value, making all $\beta$ used in the formula are positive, then can get positive PRS for all individuals.
Pubmed ID 37723974, 36882748, 36869222.


So which method is right.
And if the second one is recommended. Then if it is right to get the positive $\beta$ directly by $*(-1)$
Any suggestion is appreciated.
